# Using the pre-commit hook to clean code

Tags: git, githooks

Is it good form to scrub development code from my source files during a  pre-commit hook?

For example, I have code that is calling xdebug_break() and I want to remove the calls to that function from any files that have it before committing my code to the repository.  I would rather not check for the function before calling it because I am the only one that wants that function call there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It's ok to have the precommit hook modify code before committing it. For example, a development team might use the precommit hook to automatically reformat any code that is committed to automatically enforce that team coding conventions.</strike>

Based on the comment, I'm changing my answer - the svn manual specifically recommends AGAINST changing the contents of a commit because it can screw up the client side caching. Git works differently since the repository is local, but I guess the principle is the same.

As for the specific use case that you mentioned; it does seem a a little unconventional to use the precommit hook for that. Typically, the precommit hook is used for more general purposes. That said, if you're the only developer, you're free to use it however you like. Just don't forget that it's there.

Comment: As a developer, I would hate hate hate having my code modified without my knowledge. Abort if I'm not following convention, but don't modify code.

Answer (score 13):

The pre-commit [hook](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) should only be used for checking the commit, not for modifying it. So, you could use it to check if you have the undesired code in your commit, and abort the commit if you don't, but you should not use it to modify the commit in any way.

It would be possible to use a [filter attribute](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to run a program to "clean" your sources before they are committed; but I would recommend against this. Removing lines of source code can change the behavior of your program. You should not commit any work that you have not tested in the form that it is being committed.

Comment: Agreed.  I can imagine some pathological cases that might trip up some editors, such as a missing semicolon.

Comment: How about launching unit tests in your pre-commit hook? Is it a good idea to enforce passing the tests as a condition for committing?

Comment: @Fergal First of all, a pre-commit hook can't "enforce" anything; it is run locally, in your working repository, and the user can enable or disable it as they choose. Also, you don't want your commits to be that slow. People will already have done (at least some) testing on their code before committing; making them wait for all of the unit tests to run all over again just for their commit to finish would be incredibly frustrating. A good test suite for a large project may take hours to run; that should happen on a dedicated build machine, after a commit and push, not on the developer's machine